# TCPDF + pure HTML ... Create table of contents

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I want to print HTML to PDF using TCPDF so I do this:

```
$html = '<h1>Hello</h1>
How are you?
<h2>Answer</h2>
I am well, thanks';
// ... etc. Long HTML document.
$pdf->writeHTML($html);
```

The question is if there is a way how to add a table of contents. If TCPDF can recognize page numbers of headings.

I also sometimes use HTML page breaks:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

I understand that I need bookmarks. But in this case TCPDF would have to create them automatically. If I add an ID to html-heading-tag, TCPDF probably does not find it and cannot use it.

```
<h1 id="abc123">header1</h1>
// but following does not do anything:
$pdf->addTOC()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ToC page is created as the very last it will show that as the last page.

So instead use

```
$this->Cell(0, 12, ' '.$this->getAliasNumPage().' of '.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
//It will show page numbers
```

Comment: But this will show only caption "Page 2 of 10". But I need the whole table of contents. List of all headings and their page numbers. Like MS Word can create. Will this help somehow?

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible in TCPDF but may be someone differ from my point of view.